# CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST returns SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired when certificate is issued by Lets Encrypt

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

**Initial problem - Ignore and scroll to UPDATE section**

I am performing a cURL to a remote URL.
When I set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` second argument to `2` as it is suggested, it returns `SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired`

Clearly however, my remote domain *has* a valid cert. Tested with https://whatsmychaincert.com/.

The problem seems to go away if I perform the cURL directly to the `https://www.sub.domain.com/`, and appears when I perform the cURL to the folder/params address where I need to get data from (i.e. `https://www.sub.domain.com/index.php?param=one`)

However, I also tested that URL with https://whatsmychaincert.com/ and of course, the certificate chain is *valid*.

This is my code:

```
$url = 'https://www.sub.domain.com/folder/index.php';
$ch = curl_init( $url . '?param=test' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$content  = @curl_exec( $ch );

if( curl_errno( $ch ) ) {
   $content = curl_error( $ch );
}

$code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE );
curl_close( $ch );
error_log( print_r( $content, true ), 0 );
```

The logs will say `SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired` in this case.
If `$url = 'https://www.sub.domain.com/folder/index.php';` is `$url = 'www.sub.domain.com';`, then it does not throw that error.
But this makes no sense. The chain is intact, there should be no need (and is not possible anyway by my knowledge) to generate a certificate for `https://www.sub.domain.com/folder/index.php`, as long `sub.domain.com` has a valid certificate.

**UPDATE**

Suspect Lets Encrypt to be the issue cause
This problem happens on ALL domains I tried with unless the ones using certificates issued by CloudFlare or Amazon.
The others, where the issue happens, all use Lets Encrypt certificates. Valid, non-expired certificates, but the issuing authority is not CF or Amazon in this case, rather Lets Encrypt.
Very easily replicable, just use this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$errorFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/curl_error.txt';
$out       = fopen($errorFile, "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($out);
```

On LE certificates you will get `SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired`
On (example) netflix.com or similar Amazon/CF issued certs, you will get no error.

**Happens with the very letsencrypt.org domain too!**

Something is wrong with Lets Encrypt. Any other issuer does not present this issue.

Comment: reply to @DarkBee who's comment is removed now, asking why I pass `2` instead of `true` and that the values should be either `true` or `false`:
No, it should be 2, because true will tell you `Notice: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST no longer accepts the value 1, value 2 will be used instead in [.../path/file.php] on line XXX`, if you pass `true`. I guess PHP 8 interpretes `true` as `1`? Also, reading the PHP DOC for `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` - it says to use `2`, nothing else (unless you disable it, in which case `0` shall be used):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Seems you are correct about that one yes, my mistake. From the documentation `Support for value 1 removed in cURL 7.28.1. `

Comment: _"Happens with the very letsencrypt.org domain too!"_ - requesting `https://letsencrypt.org/` with your above code/settings, gives me no error whatsoever. `curl_error` returns an empty string, code is 200, and I get the actual content of the page.

Comment: Not in my case.
I get 
```
*   Trying 2406:da18:880:3802::c8:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to letsencrypt.org (2406:da18:880:3802::c8) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an outdated *local* certificate.

In my case, I was using MAMP. MAMP does *not* update the certificates seemingly and you need to do that manually.
Since LE's main certificate expired late September 2021, and MAMP did not update it - the cURL of course failed.

The easiest is to *install a fresh version of MAMP* freshly downloaded from their site, since they are not able to do that when MAMP (the app) performs updates.